# select the min value using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Dictionary

```
Dictionary<Location2D, int> h_scores = new Dictionary<Location2D, int>();
```

and I want to select the `Key // which is Location2D` by the minimum int value.

I tried

```
h_scores.Min().Key; // not working
h_scores.OrderBy(x => x.Value).Select(y=> y.Key).Min(); //error At least one object must implement IComparable.
```

so how can I select a key by the smallest int value?

Comment: In the second snippet, you have already ordered the sequence. Simply use `First()`, not `Min()`. For a different tactic, look up Jon Skeet's "MoreLinq" and then the `MinBy` function.

Answer (score 7):

<strike>You just need to use the right overload of [Min](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549279.aspx):</strike>

```
val minKey = h_scores.Min(s => s.Value).Key;
```

**Update**

Didn't pay attention to the return value of the overload for Min. You are definitely looking for [MinBy](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs) from Jon Skeet's morelinq:

```
val minKey = h_scores.MinBy(s => s.Value).Key;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of diversity, the solution which doesn't need external dependencies (e.g. MoreLinq) and is O(n) in contrast to `OrderBy()` solutions which are at least O(n*log(n)):

```
var minKey =
    h_scores.Aggregate(h_scores.First(), (min, curr) => curr.Value < min.Value ? curr : min).Key;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you order them by the `Value` the first one will be the one with the minimum

```
h_scores.OrderBy(x => x.Value).First().Select(y=> y.Key);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what a Location2D is but you can use the following example to do what you want.  Just sub in your class instead of string.  Also, because values are not guaranteed to be unique in a Dictionary (but may be in your case), you will likely want to do a .Single() on the keys enumeration.

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>
                         {
                             { "first", 2 },
                             { "second", 1 },
                             { "third", 3 },
                             { "fourth", 1 }
                         };

    int min = dictionary.Values.Min();
    IEnumerable<string> keys = dictionary.Keys.Where(key => dictionary[key] == min);

    Assert.That(keys.Count(), Is.EqualTo(2));
    Assert.That(keys.Contains("second"), Is.True);
    Assert.That(keys.Contains("fourth"), Is.True);
}
```